# Converted a Json file to pd dataframe but would like to pair my column data based on a specific column

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

This is a snippet of my original JSON file:

```
{
  "intents": [
    {"tag": "greeting",
     "patterns": ["Hi", "Hey", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day"],
     "responses": ["Hello, thanks for visiting ABCDE bank", "Hi there, what can I do for you?", "Hi there, how can I help?", "Welcome to ABCDE bank, how may i help you?"]
    },
```

I converted it into a PD dataframe and removed the responses column.

```
df = pd.read_json(r'intents.json')
intents = df['intents'].values.tolist()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(intents,columns =['tag', 'patterns','responses'])
df2.drop('responses', axis =1 , inplace=True)
```

I would like to arrange my patterns values based on the tag. For example:

Output:

```
tag             patterns

greeting        Hi
greeting        Hey
greeting        How are you
greeting        Is anyone there?
greeting        Hello
```

Would appreciate if anyone could help.

Comment: Just to clarify i would like my output to be in 2 columns. 1 under tag and the other patterns and to be categorised under tag because there are a few values under each pattern which falls under the specific tags.

Tag                  Pattern 
greeting          Hi
greeting          Hello
greeting          How are you

Answer (score 0):

You need to explode the dataframe, which is the reverse of groupby.

```
df2 = df2.explode(['patterns']).reset_index(drop=True)

df2
        tag          patterns
0  greeting                Hi
1  greeting               Hey
2  greeting       How are you
3  greeting  Is anyone there?
4  greeting             Hello
5  greeting          Good day
```